# SAP UI5 Smart Field Backend Validation

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've a smart field (oData value help annotation) on a form.
The suggested items and value help is working fine.
However, I would like to validate the input against the backend.
What's the proper way to perform backend validation?
And is it possible to restrict the input to value help only (valueHelpOnly option) for a smart field?

To fulfil the requirement i've implemented a read in the onChange of the field but I cannot imagine that there isn't an easier/better way..

Answer (score 0):

You can get inner control of smart field and then set `valueHelpOnly` to true.